# Stopped Service is Doing Constant Garbage Collection

Tags: android, garbage-collection

I am developing an application which has many services. When I stop the intent service, all threads and service should be stopped but the UI is hung and the following errors are in logcat:

```
2014-12-01 12: 37: 92I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 419756(33MB) AllocSpace objects, 15(4MB) LOS objects, 38% free, 25MB/41MB, paused 1.617ms total 451.976ms
2014-12-01 12: 37: 40I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 290680(16MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 25MB/33MB, paused 23.287ms total 229.513ms
2014-12-01 12: 37: 29I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 165880(9MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 23MB/39MB, paused 1.648ms total 203.601ms
2014-12-01 12: 37: 54I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 269770(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 2.533ms total 207.538ms
2014-12-01 12: 37: 54I/art     (32099): WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 170.151ms for cause HeapTrim
2014-12-01 12: 37: 22I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 155347(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 23MB/39MB, paused 1.464ms total 181.474ms
2014-12-01 12: 38: 45I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 267766(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.556ms total 149.855ms
2014-12-01 12: 38: 11I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 137696(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.617ms total 125.255ms
2014-12-01 12: 38: 82I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 148859(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 23MB/39MB, paused 1.373ms total 216.542ms
2014-12-01 12: 38: 11I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 276636(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.403ms total 156.661ms
2014-12-01 12: 38: 97I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 139573(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.464ms total 115.336ms
2014-12-01 12: 38: 85I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 151267(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 23MB/39MB, paused 2.227ms total 210.346ms
2014-12-01 12: 38: 44I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 268102(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.495ms total 148.542ms
2014-12-01 12: 38: 27I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 137761(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.587ms total 119.121ms
2014-12-01 12: 38: 26I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 154492(9MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 23MB/39MB, paused 2.533ms total 314.939ms
2014-12-01 12: 38: 75I/art     (32099): Thread[5,tid=32108,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb8111d98,peer=0x12c07080,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
2014-12-01 12: 38: 79W/art     (32099): Suspending all threads took: 13.062ms
2014-12-01 12: 38: 80I/art     (32099): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
2014-12-01 12: 38: 89I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 278516(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 25% free, 23MB/31MB, paused 2.533ms total 1.049s
2014-12-01 12: 38: 13I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 137132(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 23MB/39MB, paused 4.211ms total 188.951ms
2014-12-01 12: 38: 42I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 271335(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 3.998ms total 236.868ms
2014-12-01 12: 38: 41I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 143812(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 6.470ms total 201.800ms
2014-12-01 12: 38: 36I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 159223(9MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 23MB/39MB, paused 5.524ms total 215.809ms
2014-12-01 12: 38: 61I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 278158(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.922ms total 201.617ms
2014-12-01 12: 38: 41I/art     (32099): WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 46.696ms for cause HeapTrim
2014-12-01 12: 38: 79I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 136821(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.709ms total 123.729ms
2014-12-01 12: 38: 30I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 116947(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 20% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 5.554ms total 138.501ms
2014-12-01 12: 38: 44I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 117175(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 19% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 1.678ms total 104.257ms
2014-12-01 12: 38: 19I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 110760(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 26MB/32MB, paused 1.587ms total 104.959ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 37I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 88168(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 15% free, 27MB/32MB, paused 3.876ms total 114.878ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 54I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 136364(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 23MB/39MB, paused 1.648ms total 102.212ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 60I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 287788(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 3.418ms total 196.154ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 80I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 156308(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 25% free, 23MB/31MB, paused 3.998ms total 184.495ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 33I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 148206(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 23MB/39MB, paused 1.831ms total 103.738ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 59I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 283901(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 25% free, 23MB/31MB, paused 2.502ms total 144.086ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 43I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 134828(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/31MB, paused 2.533ms total 130.291ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 44I/art     (32099): WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 94.277ms for cause HeapTrim
2014-12-01 12: 39: 95I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 133441(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 24MB/31MB, paused 5.035ms total 139.722ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 47I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 148395(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 23MB/39MB, paused 2.227ms total 122.722ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 79I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 280706(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.495ms total 175.156ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 44I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 144094(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 2.258ms total 140.119ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 06I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 152123(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 23MB/39MB, paused 1.892ms total 108.957ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 99I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 281291(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 25% free, 23MB/31MB, paused 6.104ms total 201.190ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 02I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 136650(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/31MB, paused 41.049ms total 120.372ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 56I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 134333(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 24MB/31MB, paused 1.831ms total 130.260ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 15I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 145994(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 24MB/40MB, paused 1.800ms total 302.243ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 49I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 285630(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 2.716ms total 235.434ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 30I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 147718(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 3.845ms total 176.560ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 94I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 157542(9MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 23MB/39MB, paused 1.831ms total 178.879ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 39I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 278485(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.495ms total 219.105ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 90I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 147110(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.495ms total 143.293ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 44I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 139322(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 2.197ms total 171.036ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 10I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 155748(9MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 24MB/40MB, paused 4.455ms total 268.915ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 06I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 283584(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.770ms total 226.094ms
2014-12-01 12: 39: 13I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 14809(850KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 5.920ms total 63.573ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 05I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 149252(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 23MB/39MB, paused 1.556ms total 177.445ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 74I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 277718(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 3.631ms total 164.901ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 29I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 144490(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.464ms total 134.198ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 81I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 139991(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.709ms total 127.941ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 38I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 135726(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 22% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 1.495ms total 168.411ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 86I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 155118(9MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 23MB/39MB, paused 1.403ms total 217.701ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 10I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 277621(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 5.035ms total 199.694ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 91I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 137844(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.342ms total 137.830ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 51I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 133133(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 22% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.892ms total 161.056ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 92I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 148389(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 24MB/40MB, paused 2.105ms total 201.587ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 00I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 286110(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 3.082ms total 269.739ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 88I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 147157(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.403ms total 142.682ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 23W/art     (32099): Suspending all threads took: 20.692ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 38I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 142717(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 26.003ms total 177.750ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 04I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 152961(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 24MB/40MB, paused 3.692ms total 252.952ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 36I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 285533(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.190ms total 201.770ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 01I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 142805(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 3.876ms total 194.781ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 57I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 154279(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 23MB/39MB, paused 2.716ms total 242.118ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 46I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 282196(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 25MB/33MB, paused 1.861ms total 261.071ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 05I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 150004(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.617ms total 153.059ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 88I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 141501(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 3.204ms total 143.842ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 32I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 137981(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 1.861ms total 121.806ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 07I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 132198(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 22% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 1.526ms total 125.133ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 07I/art     (32099): WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 25.515ms for cause HeapTrim
2014-12-01 12: 40: 53I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 128414(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 21% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 2.716ms total 162.520ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 16I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 153325(9MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 24MB/40MB, paused 1.770ms total 241.812ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 14I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 281944(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 25MB/33MB, paused 1.464ms total 234.915ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 59I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 152568(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 11.628ms total 135.602ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 29I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 140163(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 2.319ms total 162.826ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 92I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 134281(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 22% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 1.983ms total 185.685ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 39I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 151800(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 24MB/40MB, paused 5.585ms total 294.216ms
2014-12-01 12: 40: 56I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 286752(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.373ms total 241.385ms
2014-12-01 12: 41: 28I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 144618(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 3.082ms total 109.446ms
2014-12-01 12: 41: 97I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 136091(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.190ms total 134.381ms
2014-12-01 12: 41: 64I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 134936(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 22% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 1.251ms total 105.356ms
2014-12-01 12: 41: 00I/art     (32099): WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 5.035ms for cause HomogeneousSpaceCompact
2014-12-01 12: 41: 51I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 124518(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 21% free, 24MB/31MB, paused 1.739ms total 130.566ms
2014-12-01 12: 41: 85I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 112812(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 20% free, 25MB/31MB, paused 1.251ms total 105.631ms
2014-12-01 12: 41: 09I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 104949(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 25MB/31MB, paused 2.350ms total 141.400ms
2014-12-01 12: 41: 40I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 125914(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 23MB/39MB, paused 1.434ms total 137.158ms
2014-12-01 12: 41: 87W/art     (32099): Suspending all threads took: 19.502ms
2014-12-01 12: 41: 05I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 276391(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 24.050ms total 233.969ms
2014-12-01 12: 41: 10I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 140307(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 1.678ms total 117.900ms
2014-12-01 12: 41: 68I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 132233(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 22% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 1.617ms total 111.521ms
2014-12-01 12: 41: 32I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 127744(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 22% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 1.587ms total 110.880ms
2014-12-01 12: 41: 62I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 124145(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 21% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 4.883ms total 117.869ms
2014-12-01 12: 41: 88I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 114064(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 19% free, 26MB/32MB, paused 1.709ms total 121.898ms
2014-12-01 12: 41: 61I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 106523(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 26MB/32MB, paused 2.166ms total 131.817ms
2014-12-01 12: 41: 34I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 99159(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 16% free, 27MB/32MB, paused 1.617ms total 132.702ms
2014-12-01 12: 41: 60I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 135913(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 23MB/39MB, paused 1.281ms total 145.856ms
2014-12-01 12: 41: 40I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 276563(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 6.775ms total 194.170ms
2014-12-01 12: 41: 40I/art     (32099): WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 41.721ms for cause HeapTrim
2014-12-01 12: 41: 62I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 135682(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 1.648ms total 105.508ms
2014-12-01 12: 41: 99I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 131287(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 22% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 2.441ms total 123.241ms
2014-12-01 12: 41: 55I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 128189(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 21% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 2.685ms total 159.987ms
2014-12-01 12: 41: 93I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 146571(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 24MB/40MB, paused 21.638ms total 212.330ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 03I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 282301(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 4.394ms total 191.423ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 46I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 144030(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.312ms total 105.020ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 16I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 135791(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 5.096ms total 134.198ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 77I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 132569(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 22% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 1.312ms total 113.871ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 49I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 158851(9MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 24MB/40MB, paused 3.540ms total 222.890ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 79I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 282779(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 25MB/33MB, paused 3.082ms total 205.371ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 31I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 145527(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.648ms total 111.857ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 93I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 136635(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 1.770ms total 109.415ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 38I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 131901(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 22% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 2.044ms total 129.558ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 93I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 127795(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 21% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 3.509ms total 128.734ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 31I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 123525(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 21% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 1.678ms total 112.131ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 61I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 120526(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 20% free, 26MB/32MB, paused 3.174ms total 112.406ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 77I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 117214(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 19% free, 26MB/32MB, paused 2.685ms total 155.501ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 27I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 146608(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 24MB/40MB, paused 1.373ms total 148.359ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 84I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 277503(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 35.006ms total 188.402ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 49I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 139325(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 2.319ms total 125.194ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 98I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 134919(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 3.357ms total 129.192ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 01I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 127642(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 21% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 1.434ms total 125.133ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 23I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 125587(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 21% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 2.350ms total 123.363ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 79I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 119217(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 20% free, 26MB/32MB, paused 5.615ms total 127.819ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 01I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 115621(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 19% free, 26MB/32MB, paused 1.800ms total 124.889ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 50I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 109559(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 19% free, 26MB/32MB, paused 1.495ms total 103.708ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 71I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 103671(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 17% free, 27MB/32MB, paused 4.028ms total 137.524ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 84I/art     (32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 140033(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 24MB/40MB, paused 1.648ms total 222.646ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 79I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 285098(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 12.055ms total 181.199ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 24I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 143445(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.556ms total 119.517ms
2014-12-01 12: 42: 75I/art     (32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 138529(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 25MB/32MB, paused 1.892ms total 128.673ms
```

what could be the issue? and how can it be fixed?

Comment: I had the same issue and discovered that it was due to a circular reference problem when serializing an object to JSON, using Gson library.  Generated JSON was infinite, and memory isn't, so app stalled.  I know it sounds idiot, but it's true, :-)

Comment: Nope dear....but i think if we called intent service repeatedly then this problem is occur.

Comment: Can you show some code? How are you starting the service? Does it extend IntentService or Service? What work are you doing in the service? By default a Service starts in the UI thread. You need to create a separate worker thread do not hang the UI.

Comment: It is basically a intent service.

Comment: Something is allocating and releasing a lot of objects and doing so continuously.  We'll need code to help you further.

Comment: I suggest you use the memory tracker to check what is allocated all the time, it will lead you to the solution. Its harder to be more specific without code. https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

Answer (score 8):

Profile your app - I found the cause of my similar problem that way.

> Android Studio: Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor

Select your app and it the top (left) select:

> Start method profiling

and after some time stop it the see the result.

Comment: This helped me to identify, that Json pretty formatting was called on each network request. :/ Thanks!

Comment: tutorial for method profiling http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem also occured for me. But I am using SqLite. When I want to select List of my entity I forgot to add some important methods. When problem occured my code is following

```
 public List<Blocked> getBlockeds() {
    List<Blocked> blockeds = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] allColumns = {"id", "phoneNumber"};
    Cursor cursor = database.query("Blockeds", allColumns, null, null, null, null, "id desc");
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Blocked blocked = new CursorToPojo().cursorToBlocked(cursor);
        blockeds.add(blocked);
    }
    return blockeds;
}
```

When change code to following the problem solved.

```
public List<Blocked> getBlockeds() {
    List<Blocked> blockeds = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] allColumns = {"id", "phoneNumber"};
    Cursor cursor = database.query("Blockeds", allColumns, null, null, null, null, "id desc");
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Blocked blocked = new CursorToPojo().cursorToBlocked(cursor);
        blockeds.add(blocked);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return blockeds;
}
```

I realised that when I did not use `cursor.moveToNext` cursor never end and the preceding problem start.

Answer (score 0):

I Don't see a reason for using Intent service when there's need for the service to be stopped.
But if you still think it has to be done then either make call to stopself() from onhandleIntent itself (which will again break the protocol), or you can call it from your activity(which is prone to stop queue processing which is pending).

i Would rather go with bounded services if i have to manage their whole lifecycle.
Here's the reference::

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html