# Retrofit GET results in a stack size error, 1036 KB

Tags: android, stack, retrofit

I have been trying to apply the RetroFit REST Client in my application and I have run into a problem, that I can not seem to solve. I try to download a .json file (services.hanselandpetal.com/feeds/flowers.json) and after several seconds of downloading I keep getting a stackoverflow error:

"com.dbflowtest.MainActivity﹕ retrofit.RetrofitError: stack size 1036KB".

Below the code that I use:

FlowerAPI.java

```
public interface FlowerAPI {

    @GET("/feeds/flowers.json")
    public void getFeed(Callback<List<Flower>> response); 
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
private void requestFlowers() {
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
            .build();

    FlowerAPI api = adapter.create(FlowerAPI.class);

    api.getFeed(new Callback<List<Flower>>() {

        @Override
        public void success(List<Flower> flowers, Response response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Received flowers.")
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Flower.java

```
@Table(databaseName = AppDatabase.NAME) 
public class Flower extends BaseModel {

    @Column(columnType = Column.PRIMARY_KEY)
    public int productId;

    @Column
    public String category;

    @Column
    public double price;

    @Column
    public String instructions;

    @Column
    public String photo;

    @Column
    public String name;

    private List<Flower> flowers;

    public Flower() {}

    public Flower(int productId, String category, double price, String instructions, String photo, String name) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.category = category;
        this.price = price;
        this.instructions = instructions;
        this.photo = photo;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Flower> getFlowers() {
        if(flowers == null) {
            flowers = new Select()
                .from(Flower.class)
                .queryList();
        }
        return flowers;
    }
}
```

I cannot seem to solve this problem. Any help is greatly appreciated, as I would really like to use this framework :).

SOLVED

For some reason I get this stack size problem when I use the POJO for both Retrofit and DBFlow. So instead of having 1 Flower.java class, I made another named FlowerDB.java. This solved my problem!

Comment: Is the error stack overflow or stack size ? And I just tested this code and it works. I think you need to post Flower class.

Comment: Thank you for testing it. I just posted my Flower.java class. I think the only relevant fields are the attributes. The annotations are for DBFlow. And to answer your question, I get a stack size problem, not a stackoverflow :).

Comment: It still works. What if you remove all the annotations ? And have you tried calling different api ?

Comment: I have removed all the annotations and I do not get the stack size error anymore, but it just keeps downloading. How long does it take you to download the .json file? Also, I have only used RetroFit so far with the GET command shown above. Have you got any suggestions for what other API I should use?

Comment: I have some additional information that may be important. I think something is wrong with garbage collection. I get the same output as the guy in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27224175/stopped-service-is-doing-constant-garbage-collection

Comment: I don't think it's the problem. I can download and parse it almost instantly. This may sound stupid but have you declared internet permission in manifest?

Comment: Hehe yes I have :) I did run into that one aswell. Anyway, I recreated the project and left out the DBFlow imports and it works now. Honestly I have no idea why I got this error, but at least it works now :).

Answer (score 0):

There is a much better way, that allows to keep the same POJO objects for both Retrofit and DBFlow.

*(Having 2 POJO for the same object is a pain in the ass when you want to load/update values from one aspect to the other. Believe me, I tried....)*

This is an issue from GSon implementation used by Retrofit, which is lost inside the `ModelAdapter` object of DBFlow.

You should thus replace this code :

```
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
        .build();
```

by

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                    return f.getDeclaredClass().equals(ModelAdapter.class);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .create();

    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
            .build();
```

And suddenly, loading your JSON will be working like a charm...