# A note in console while restarting a flutter application

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

while  creating  a flutter application , I restarted the application and after that a note poped out in dubug console

```
Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 187009(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 53% free, 6MB/14MB, paused 5.282ms total 60.228ms
```

I wanted to know why do we get this, and what does it mean?
I googled it out but I cant find any thing related to it , So it would be very helpful  if someone would answer  it...

Comment: See this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381474/background-sticky-concurrent-mark-sweep-gc-freed/42381701)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to do with the debugging garbage collector.

A garbage collector frees up spare memory that isn't in use, automatically. You can find it in languages such as C and Java - which is what Dart (sometimes) compiles to (simplified). The storage stats you see are to do with how much memory it freed, and you can see it took 60ms in the background.

This is totally normal, and you shouldn't be concerned. AFAIK, you can't hide the log; you definitely shouldn't be able to stop the process.

Comment: Dart doesn't compile to C or Java - it has its own VM, even when AOT compiled.

Comment: @RichardHeap Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43854647/flutter-how-does-it-work-behind-the-scenes. Although Flutter does not directly compile like a normal app might (as you said it has a VM for AOT compliation), it uses the compiler (for Android, idk about iOS) Gradle, to convert to Java. For further evidence, please see https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/test-drive?tab=terminal: you can change the --android-language from the default Java. Android cannot run Flutter apps directly. To be sure, however, I'll edit my original post.

Comment: Again, no - there is no _conversion_ to Java or Swift. It's true that a Flutter app runs some Dart code and some native code (in different threads, communicating by platform channels), the Dart code is compiled directly to native and the native code is compiled by the 'normal' platform build tool, (In Flutter web it's slightly different - the Dart code compiles to Javascript and the 'native' code is also Javascript.)

Comment: Ok, I'm not 100% sure still, but there's no point arguing.